# SSL_SERVER_S_DN_Email shows incorrect email in PHP var_dump

Tags: php, apache, ldap, single-sign-on, httpd.conf

I am configuring a web app (Bugzilla) that has User Authentication parameters to allow for SSO if correctly set using the Environment Variables. I have previously set up another web app (TestLink) in a similar fashion. I am trying to use PHP's var_dump to see if the correct email is being passed to the app, since it originally did not work as intended. While looking through the var_dump I noticed under my test user that the email for my administrative account was actually being shown in the var_dump, and the test user's email account was not.

I've currently configured my ssl.conf file inside of /httpd/conf.d as follows:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/testing>
Order deny, allow
Deny from All
AuthName "Company Intranet"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
#AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPUrl ldaps://389.comp.loc/dc=comp,dc=loc?uid
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
#AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=,OU=Service Accounts,OU=IS,OU=FSA,DC=comp,DC=loc"
#AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute on
#AuthLDAPBindPassword password
</Directory>
```

My test.php page has this script

```
<?php
phpinfo();
session_start();
setcookie();
var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($_COOKIE);
?>
```

Comment: You may want to look up what `SSL_SERVER_S_DN_Email` is. Note the use of the word "server" in the name.

Comment: Sadly those are the only email addresses showing in the var_dump

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer a few weeks ago, the AuthLDAPUrl needs to be like this...

```
AuthLDAPUrl ldaps://389.comp.loc/dc=comp,dc=loc?uid**,mail,cn,givenname,sn**
```